# Partially visible occluded sprites

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, sprite

I would like to reproduce a behavior from the app on the screenshots. I.e. when a sprite is occluded by a mesh, it stays partially visible, even it is now behind the mesh in the foreground. 
Any tips or hints how this could be achieved in ThreeJS? Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

It can be done with a single sprite, but you probably would have to utilize a shaderMaterial (Disable depthTest and check in the vertex/fragment shader if the pixelCoordinate is below ground level, then render it transparent).

If you're not familiar with this, another way is to double up the sprites. The trick is to set depthTest on one of them to false. That way the sprite is rendered, even if it is underneath the ground. (When it is above the ground it is still rendered on top of the other sprite, but it is almost transparent, so not really noticeable).

I made a small example here; https://jsfiddle.net/EthanHermsey/kw7dn8bh/25/

```
//create 2 sprites
let sprite = new THREE.Sprite(
    new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
    color: 'red'
  })
)
sprite.scale.setScalar( 0.5 );

let sprite2 = new THREE.Sprite(
    new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
    color: 'red',
    opacity: 0.2,
    transparent: true,
    depthTest: false
  })
)
sprite2.scale.setScalar( 0.5 );

//create a container for both sprites, add sprites to it.
spriteContainer = new THREE.Object3D();
spriteContainer.add(sprite)
spriteContainer.add(sprite2)
scene.add(spriteContainer);
```

Comment: Man, you made my day. The solution with the double sprites is just awesome. Simple and working perfect for my use case. Thanks sir!

Comment: Wow, this double sprite trick is a great idea, it helped me a lot with a similar problem.